# Can Mongo use a reference and compare values during aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53f7287881a97c71e58e3514"),
        "title" : "My Page",
        "currentVersion" : 1,
        "versions" : [ 
            {
                "version" : 0,
                "content" : [ 
                    {
                        "data" : "foo",
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "version" : 1,
                "content" : [ 
                    {
                        "data" : "bar",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Is there anyway, (via the aggregation framework or otherwise) to perform a document projection where the only content in `versions` is the one that satisfies `versions.version==currentVersion` for each document? I understand that the first step might be to $unwind but I'm stumped as to how to filter out documents where `currentVersion!=versions.version`.

Ideally, I would like to dispense with `versions.version` and use `currentVersion` as a positional pointer for `versions`.

Thanks!

### Update

I've come up with the following, which does the trick, but feels slightly inelegant

```
db.test.aggregate(
    [        
        { $unwind: "$versions" },
        { $project: 
            {
                title:1,
                versionMatch: { $cmp: [ "$currentVersion","$versions.version"] },
                content: "$versions.content"
            }
        },
        { $match: 
            {
                versionMatch: {$eq:0}
            }
        },
        { $project: 
            {
                title:1,
                content: 1              
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

The better solution would be to be able to pluck the entry directly from `versions`using `currentVersion` as a pointer but I am not sure that's entirely possible.

Comment: Your (update) solution is correct and cannot be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can improve upon this. Provided you have MongoDB 2.6 or greater then you can actually filter your already unique versions without needing to process an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). This makes use of the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators introduced as of that release:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "title": 1,
       "content": {
           "$setDifference": [
               { "$map": {
                   "input": "$versions",
                   "as": "el",
                   "in": {
                       "$cond": [
                           { "$eq": [ "$currentVersion", "$$el.version" ] },
                           "$$el.content",
                           false
                       ]
                   }
               }},
               [false]
           ]
       }
    }}
])
```

Or even possibly with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) that is also introduced. Mind that this is recursive so this involves an arbitrary "project" of a matching value where the field to compare does not exist:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
   { "$redact": {
       "$cond": [
           { "$eq": [ 
               { "$ifNull": [ "$version", "$$ROOT.currentVersion" ] },
               "$ROOT.currentVersion"
           ]},
           "$$DESCEND",
           "$$PRUNE"
       ]
   }}
])
```

Both will match the "versions" content to the "currentVersion" and remove other elements, though both do still keep a nested array and even the latter without the prettier projection, but you can always process [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on these with little performance penalty as the data is already reduced to one match.

Earlier versions of MongoDB of course do not have the operators required to do this, so you are pretty much stuck with using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to get a logical match between the two:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$versions" },
  { "$project": {
      "title": 1,
      "content": "$versions.content",
      "matched": {
          "$eq": [ "$currentVersion", "$versions.version" ]
      }  
  }},
  { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

Noting that in all cases the best logical test is with [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) as [**`$cmp`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/) should only be needed where the BSON Type varies such as `NumberLong` and `NumberInt` or you actually intend to compare types in by [comparison order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order). It should also be more efficient being a basic test.

For larger result sets, dropping that final [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) helps as well since the cost of processing through all results just to strip an unwanted field outweighs any benefit of doing so, and your generally better of ignoring or otherwise removing in post processing.

But where possible the first two forms will give the best performance which is largely due to removing the need to "unwind" which produces significantly more documents to process in the pipeline stages.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned in the original post that my mongo version is < 2.6 so I can't use any of the new features. But your second version works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Ioannis But you **can** use the more optimized last example as shown. And it **does** give you dome compelling reasons to consider an upgrade as well.

Comment: yes the last one was the one I was referring to. The other two I considered them as one entity under 2.6+, which I can't use at the moment :-)