# comparing a string field to a sub-array field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

There are 2 collections with each containing details as below:

> Collection 1 (prpackages): {Server, Package, Version}
>   Collection 2 (qapackages): {Server, Package, Version}.

I need to get the package name from collection 1 and compare it against the same package on collection 2 using the version number (string field).

I used `$lookup` in aggregation to merge the 2 collections and the matching packages gets append as a array, but when I try to compare the string values of the field and sub array field using `$match`, it returns a no values.

**MongoDB Enterprise > db.prpackages.find()**

> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40762"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542346", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-sysctl_conf", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40763"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542347", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-authorized_keys", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40764"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542348", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntp_conf", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40765"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542350", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-rootcron", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e6280392ae96de6a40766"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542352", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntpd", "version" : "1"}

**MongoDB Enterprise > db.qapackages.find()**

> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e630c392ae96de6a40776"), "server" :
>   "ln1244234", "installedTime" : "1399324250", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-sysctl_conf", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e630c392ae96de6a40777"), "server" :
>   "ln1244234", "installedTime" : "1399324251", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-authorized_keys", "version" : "1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e630d392ae96de6a40778"), "server" :
>   "ln1244234", "installedTime" : "1399324252", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntp_conf", "version" : "1.2.1"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e630d392ae96de6a40779"), "server" :
>   "ln1244234", "installedTime" : "1399324254", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-rootcron", "version" : "2"}
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e630e392ae96de6a4077a"), "server" :
>   "ln1244234", "installedTime" : "1399324255", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntpd", "version" : "1"}

**Merged using aggregate and lookup, the results looks like:**

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.prpackages.aggregate([ {$lookup: {from: "qapackages", localField: "package", foreignField: "package", as: "qacoll"}} ])
```

> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40762"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542346", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-sysctl_conf", "versionNum" : "1", "qacoll" : [ {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("596e630c392ae96de6a40776"), "server" : "ln1244234",
>   "installedTime" : "1399324250", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-sysctl_conf", "versionNum" : "1" ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40763"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542347", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-authorized_keys", "versionNum" : "1", "qacoll" : [ {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("596e630c392ae96de6a40777"), "server" : "ln1244234",
>   "installedTime" : "1399324251", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-authorized_keys", "versionNum" : "1"} ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40764"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542348", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntp_conf", "versionNum" : "1", "qacoll" : [ { "_id"
>   : ObjectId("596e630d392ae96de6a40778"), "server" : "ln1244234",
>   "installedTime" : "1399324252", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntp_conf", "versionNum" : "1.2.1"} ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e627f392ae96de6a40765"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542350", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-rootcron", "versionNum" : "1", "qacoll" : [ { "_id"
>   : ObjectId("596e630d392ae96de6a40779"), "server" : "ln1244234",
>   "installedTime" : "1399324254", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-rootcron", "versionNum" : "2"} ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596e6280392ae96de6a40766"), "server" :
>   "ln1244567", "installedTime" : "1393542352", "package" :
>   "hd-str-sa-config-ntpd", "versionNum" : "1", "qacoll" : [ { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("596e630e392ae96de6a4077a"), "server" : "ln1244234",
>   "installedTime" : "1399324255", "package" : "hd-str-sa-config-ntpd",
>   "versionNum" : "1"} ] }

**Queries:**

Works when using a value for comparison:

```
db.prpackages.aggregate([ {$lookup: {from: "qapackages", localField: "package", foreignField: "package", as: "qacoll"}}, {$match: {"qacoll.version": {$eq:  "1"}}} ])
```

Not working when compared against another field of the subarray:

```
db.prpackages.aggregate([ {$lookup: {from: "qapackages", localField: "package", foreignField: "package", as: "qacoll"}}, {$match: {"qacoll.version": {$eq:  "$version"}}} ])
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: format please your data as code. It would be more readable.

Comment: You actually want [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in a regular [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) here. Possibly [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact) if you simply mean to remove both parent and child if the condition is not met. `$match` does not "use field values" and works just like a regular `.find()`. Use the other operators for field comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I am able to figure it out, plus I learnt that its a duplicate of the question.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509644/can-mongo-use-a-reference-and-compare-values-during-aggregation/25657413#25657413